# Flutter to generate Word (.docx) with images inserted in Table

Tags: flutter, ms-word, flutter-packages, flutter-image, flutter-table

I am in process of making a Flutter App where we can select pictures and then generate a MS word file with selected images inserted in Table. Initially I though I will generate a pdf with table and convert to word and made progress on that. I generated pdf but when I convert to word I see its getting converted as one big image and not as Table with images as I need to alter images sometimes in word. Now I am struck can anyone help with some way forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this package [docx_template](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/docx_template)

```dart
final f = File("template.docx");
  final docx = await DocxTemplate.fromBytes(await f.readAsBytes());


  // Load test image for inserting in docx
  final testFileContent = await File('test.jpg').readAsBytes();



  Content c = Content();
  c
    ..add(TextContent("docname", "Simple docname"))
    ..add(TableContent("table", [
      RowContent()
        ..add(TextContent("key1", "Paul"))
        ..add(ImageContent('img', testFileContent)),
    ]))

      

  final d = await docx.generate(c);
  final of = File('generated.docx');
  if (d != null) await of.writeAsBytes(d);
```

Comment: Hi I tried the code I get the following error message
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'generated.docx' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)
is it something to do with permission    ?

Comment: Yes it worked thanks for the help in flutter I Just changed the below lines.  
   `
 final d = await docx.generate(c);
    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File('${dir.path}/generated.docx');
    if (d != null) await file.writeAsBytes(d);
`

Comment: Is there a way to create AnchorElement of the same file for flutter web ?